# Почему BeautifulSoup возвращает []?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

num = '+79031234567'
responce = requests.post(f'https://phonenum.info/phone/7{num}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.content, 'html.parser')
operator = soup.find_all("div", class_="paramValue", id="mnp_ported_operator")

print(f'ОПЕРАТОР: {operator}')
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в `url`.
Нужно передать номер без `+`, а вы передаете номер с `+` да еще и с цифрой перед ним.
В вашем случае `url` выглядит так: `https://phonenum.info/phone/7+79031234567`, на надо так: `https://phonenum.info/phone/79031234567`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

num = '79031234567'
responce = requests.post(f'https://phonenum.info/phone/{num}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.content, 'html.parser')
operator = soup.find_all("div", class_="paramValue", id="mnp_ported_operator")

print(f'ОПЕРАТОР: {operator}')
```